# Media Query for mobile landscape

Tags: html, ios, css, media-queries, responsive

I am trying to target mobile landscape mode with css query, I thought its going to be simple but it wasn't, I am using following query its working on Android but on iPhone it doesn't.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 750px) and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

I also tried adding `(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)` but doesn't work.

What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The sizes and pixel-ratio will vary depending on the phone you're currently developing for; however here is the media query for the iPhone X.

```css
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 
  
  /* iPhone X styles here */
  ...
}
```

[Source & more information for different devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: I wanted to use 1 query not specific query for each model.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try some of this media-query:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5, 5S, 5C and 5SE ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone X ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```